# Setting the split editor sensitivity - VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

I want to be able to split the editor when I drag them but not have to point as much at the corners of the editor when I drag them

The red line is the minimum distance for the horizontal division option to come out, which is approximately 10% of the width of the editor

Is there any configuration in vs-code that allows to increase that?

[image]

Comment: I just don't understand why they chose such a small space. As if when I'm dragging a tab, I want to align it with itself.